# Create function that reverse words but preserves any spaces?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an issue creating a function that both reverses the input string AND preserves any extra spaces in it. For example:

```
reverse("this is a string"); // should return: "siht si a gnirts"
```

And if we have something like:

```
reverse("this is     a string"); // then should be: "siht si     a gnirts"
```

But I'm hitting a brick wall mentally coming up with how to account for both. I know it should be easy .. I feel stupid :/

Here is what I have so far (only works for the first part):

```
function reverseWords($str) {
    return implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', strrev($str)))) ;
}
```

Comment: You doing a whiteboard coding interview or something? That's the only time I've ever seen this requirement

Comment: Yes, it's a whiteboard coding question in a book I'm reading. I'm preparing for the interview process.

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't worded very well but this isn't _"reverses the input string AND preserves any extra spaces"_. Your requirement is to reverse each word within the string, maintaining word position and spacing. Hopefully your real interview questions are clearer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to split on space, then [**map**](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php) each entry to the [*string-reversed*](https://www.php.net/manual/function.strrev.php) version of itself before joining the new array back together

```php
function reverseWords($str) {
    return implode(' ', array_map('strrev', explode(' ', $str)));
}

echo reverseWords("this is a string");
// siht si a gnirts

echo reverseWords("this is     a string");
// siht si     a gnirts
```

https://3v4l.org/hTle3